# How to decode the protobuf binary serialization at reactjs

Tags: django, reactjs, protocol-buffers

I have a django web app, I am sending the protobuf as my response at view end , but I don't have any idea how should I decode at reactjs end.

I am new to reactjs still I am at learning phase

Comment: If we have any CDN to support it, it helps me great

Comment: Are you using the Google implementation? If so, isn't this a case of following the guide, presumably using the common js option? https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated

Answer (score 0):

Fact that you are using React is irrelevant to your question. You decode protobuf messages like in any other javascript program, and as described in official protobuf documentation and in many existing examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use protoc plugin to first convert proto file to .ts file if anyone is using a typescript

Go through this for better clarity - https://github.com/improbable-eng/ts-protoc-gen

```
sudo protoc --plugin=../node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts_proto --ts_proto_opt=esModuleInterop=true --ts_proto_out=. *.proto
```

After that, we can consume API like this -

```
import { Reader } from "protobufjs";

const response = YourProtoBufResponseMessage.decode(Reader.create(uint8));
```